# How do Oregon's mayoral elections work?

Tags: united-states, election, local-government, oregon

I'm writing an RPG campaign that takes place in a city of Oregon. However, taking a look in lists of mayors of some cities, I found that some mayors have mandates of only one year, despite others having even nineteen years. I don't know if this happens in other states of the USA, so I put "Oregon" in the title because I am more interested in this one.

So, I would like to know:

How often do the elections normally occur?

What is causing that huge difference in the duration of various mandates?

If this pattern is not valid in all Oregon's cities, I am more interest in Portland's election. Salem's fits me well too, but only if an answer about Portland is being hard to find.

Comment: The question is quite broad - is it OK to focus on the main aspect only - "why there is so much difference between durations of some mandates..."?

Comment: I think that I put it more clear now

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the city? I would imagine most cities have their own rules for electing mayors.

Comment: @Chipster I have check Portland and Salem and both have this irregular pattern of mandates.

Comment: Do you have any material regarding Salem's mayoral election? https://www.cityofsalem.net/Pages/run-for-elected-city-office.aspx indicates that mayors serve 2 year terms, which doesn't strike me as strange at all.

Comment: Well, if you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayors_of_Portland,_Oregon
,on the last mayors, you can see a irregular duration of mandates. I'm wonder why this occurs

Comment: @pipinstallMonica I did not find again the historial list of mayors of Salem, but here you can take a look on the Portland's list. Why this irregular pattern occur?

Comment: Presumably some mayors are re-elected. The vast majority of the rest (after 1913) look like they're serving normal 4 year terms. I'd imagine some are shorter (or off the 4 year schedule) because they left mid-term due to illness/scandal/death/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Q: How do Oregon's mayoral elections work?*

The League of Oregon Cities *[Oregon Municipal Handbook – Chapter 3: Municipal Officials](https://www.orcities.org/application/files/2315/9917/4968/Handbook_-_Chapter_3_Municipal_Officials.pdf)* provides information on variations in government organization among cities in Oregon.

> How often do the elections normally occur?

Every two or four years.

> What is causing that huge difference in the duration of various mandates?

Some cities have term-limits, others don't.

> If this pattern is not valid in all Oregon's cities, I am more interest in Portland's election.

There is a variety of organization among different cities. Cities may have a council or commission with from five to nine members. The Mayor may be elected by voters or appointed by the council. Some cities have a city manager (or administrator) hired by the council.

##### [Portland](https://www.portland.gov/elections/city-office-candidacy)

> All City elected officials serve four-year terms and are elected at-large. All candidates for an office appear on the May Primary ballot. A candidate is elected if they receive a majority of votes. If no candidate receives a majority of votes, the two candidates receiving the highest number of votes advance to the November General Election ballot. The candidate receiving the most votes in November is then elected.

> - The Mayor and Commissioners No. 1 and 4 are elected during presidential elections.

> - The Auditor and Commissioners No. 2 and 3 are elected during midterm elections.

However, a change in the above will take effect [after the 2024 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Portland,_Oregon).

> In 2022, Portland residents approved a ballot measure to replace the commission form of government with a 12-member council elected in four districts using single transferable vote, with a professional city manager appointed by a directly-elected mayor, with the first elections to be held in 2024.

##### [Salem](https://www.cityofsalem.net/government/city-council-mayor/elections-run-for-elected-city-office)

> The elected officials of the City are the Mayor, eight City Councilors, and the Municipal Judge.

Salem also has a city manager.

> Mayor (unpaid volunteer position) - 2 years

> City Councilor (unpaid volunteer position) - 4 years